# python - how can I use web browser click and download a file

Tags: python, browser

Workflow:

- Website:

  - doesn't have an API
  - requires login
  - clicking on a button to download a file

    - Is a Javascript button
- save file to a download location

Question:

1. Is there a way to do this through python?

Comment: Selenium? Have you tried that?

Comment: I just came across Selenium.  After posting this.  Is Selenium the best to do this? or is there other recommended alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

It uses a chrome driver (or firefox) and can simulate javascript.

Here is an example for clicking a button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://codepad.org')

# click radio button
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='lang' and @value='Python']")[0]
python_button.click()

# type text
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
text_area.send_keys("print('Hello World')")

# click submit button
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editor"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input')[0]
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: I just came across this but was wondering is selenium is the best available option?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Selenium to mimic the browser environment.

1. Try to login by giving your credentials using selenium.
2. find the button tag and use the html-tag-id to click on it.
3. Try to find the download location of the file / try to download it directly using the button

Comment: This will be a general solution, but if you want to get the code, please specify the website address.

Comment: I just came across this but was wondering is selenium is the best available option?

Comment: Selenium is a widely used tool for automated testing of broswers & websites.